# Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode - Issue while persisting

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, persistence, spring-transactions

I have been facing the below error while trying to save the object to database. I tried the solution mentioned [here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810158/java-hibernate-write-operations-are-not-allowed-in-read-only-mode) and [here2](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/65361-invaliddataaccessapiusageexception) but no good. I was following a [tutorial](http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-hibernate-dao-support.jsp) but the only difference is versions of Spring and Hibernate.

I am able to persist the object directly using the SessionFactory but it fails with below error if I try this with HibernateDaoSupport

**spring.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
    <property name="username" value="system" />
    <property name="password" value="xxx" />
</bean>

<context:annotation-config/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.sri.sphiber.model"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>



<bean id="customerDAOImpl" class="org.sri.sphiber.dao.CustomerDAOImpl">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> 
</bean>
```

**CustomerDAOImpl.java**

```
public class CustomerDAOImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport {

    public boolean insertCustomer(Customer cust){

        try {
            getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(cust);
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Invoke it using.**

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


            ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
            CustomerDAOImpl hdi=appContext.getBean("customerDAOImpl",CustomerDAOImpl.class);


            Customer customer=new Customer();
            customer.setCustomerName("Sri");

            boolean isUpdated = hdi.insertCustomer(customer);

    }


}
```

**Error message.**

```
Aug 10, 2014 12:45:52 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.checkWriteOperationAllowed(HibernateTemplate.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$16.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:684)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:340)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:308)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(HibernateTemplate.java:681)
    at org.sri.sphiber.dao.CustomerDAOImpl.insertCustomer(CustomerDAOImpl.java:16)
    at org.sri.sphiber.main.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:26)
```

**Version Details :**

```
Spring version : spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE
Hibernate Version : hibernate-release-4.3.5.Final
Database : Orcale 11g
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing TransactionManager definition, see http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

[UPDATE]
Previously i was writing from my mobile so it was hard to provide details, here is what you need to do:

1. Spring xml config:

   ```
   <tx:annotation-driven/>
   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> 
   </bean>
   ```
2. Add @Transactional annotation to CustomerDaoImpl.insertCustomer method

Now your code should work. 
**Please note** that @Transactional annotation should be used in service layer, not in DAO layer like in this example. 
@Transactional annotation tells spring to create proxy which "wraps" annotated method with transaction using aspects.

Comment: I added the TransactionManager as suggested by you (edited the question) , but still got the same error, I dint quite follow that. Can you please explain a bit more on this ? Thanks.

Comment: It just worked like charm, it was looking for a bean named transactionManager instead of txManager. Let me take a look at the docs again. I guess I miss understood the way it works. :) Thanks a lot

Comment: If you configure your spring application programmatically you can add @ EnableTransactionManagement annotation which is the equivalent for <tx:annotation-driven/>. So just add @EnableTransactionManagement annotation to your @ Configuration annotated class.

Answer (score 0):

In configuration file

do the change:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement   <-----Put this line
public PersistenceConfig{
//your code
}
```

(OR)

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate(SessionFactory session) {
        HibernateTemplate hb = new HibernateTemplate();
        hb.setCheckWriteOperations(false);
        hb.setSessionFactory(session);
        return hb;
    }
```